# terraform cyclic dependeny for aws api gateway with resource policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

**Problem statement**
i am trying to automate aws api gateway with terraform follwing is part of my code

*for api gateway*

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api" {
  #some code
policy = "${data.template_file.init.rendered}"
}

output "id" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
}

output "execution_arn" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.execution_arn}"
}

output "arn" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.arn}"
}
```

*for resource policy*
please note i want to automate insertion of api id in json policy document

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("${path.root}/${var.policy_file_location}")}"
  vars = {
    current_region      = "${data.aws_region.current.name}"
    current_aws_account = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
    current_api_id              = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}"
  }
}
```

json policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:${current_region}:${current_aws_account}:${current_api_id}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

when i try to provide resource policy similar to following i am getting

> Error: Cycle: module.simple-api-gw.data.template_file.init,
>   module.simple-api-gw.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api

how can I resolve this error? I want to provide api id dynamically in json file.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  I ended up harding the the api id in variables.tf and the inserted that into the policy using that variable. It is still hard-coding (and after the fact), but at least I didn't have to hardcode id IN THE policy.

Answer (score 2):

The policy you are generating would be [appropriate to assign to an IAM role or IAM user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html), to allow them to invoke the API. Assigning that specific policy directly to the API Gateway doesn't make sense. In essence you are saying "anyone with permission to invoke the API can have permission to invoke the API" which is a circular statement.

A policy [appropriate for assigning to an API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-policy-language-overview.html) would do something like limit requests to specific Principals, or specific IP addresses.

Please see the documentation that I have linked above. It outlines two separate methods for controlling access to your API Gateway, via IAM permissions or via resource policies. You are trying to assign an IAM permission as a resource policy, which isn't going to work.

Comment: You have a circular dependency because you are trying to apply the wrong type of IAM policy to the API Gateway. I thought I stated that clearly in my answer. You can't "resolve" this without rethinking how you are applying this IAM rule.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you are trying to refer to the output of a resource while creating it. You need not populate execution arn for resources in the policy and use "execute-api:/*" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api_policy) resource to attach the policy to the API instead of using the "policy" attribute when creating the REST API.

Resource policies are required when creating private APIs through a VPC Endpoint.